# Maximum concurrent requests that a Self Hosted SignalR server can handle

Tags: performance, signalr, load-testing

I had been doing some load testing on SignalR server. According to my test case a Self Hosted SignalR server can handle only 20,000 concurrent requests at a time.

When SignalR has 20,000 open connections, the process consumes about 1.5 GB of RAM (I think that is too much). And when the connections exceed 22,000 the new clients get connection timeout error. Server never runs out of memory, just stops responding to new requests.

I'm aware of Server Farming, and that I can use that it in SignalR using BackPlane, but I'm concerned about Vertical Scaling here. I have achieved 25,000 connections using long polling (async asp.net handlers). I suppose signalR should be able to achieve more concurrent requests as it uses WebSockets.

Is there something I can do to have about 50,000 concurrent connections per node of SignalR? [This](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance) performance tuning is of no help because I'm using Owin self-hosting. What can I do so that my server application takes less memory per connection?

Comment: Yes. add another Signlr server lol.